# Need help in React and Framer motion animation

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-animations, framer-motion, react-animations

I'm trying to do an animation like [this](https://andagain.uk/).

There when you scroll you can see an image carousel where outer element is static and images are changing. I'm using Framer motion to achieve this.
This is the code I'm trying,

```
import { motion, useTransform, useScroll } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef } from "react";

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-neutral-800">
      <div className="flex h-48 items-center justify-center">
        <span className="font-semibold uppercase text-neutral-500">
          Scroll down
        </span>
      </div>
      <HorizontalScrollCarousel />
      <div className="flex h-48 items-center justify-center">
        <span className="font-semibold uppercase text-neutral-500">
          Scroll up
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const HorizontalScrollCarousel = () => {
  const targetRef = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: targetRef,
  });

  const x = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", "-130%"]);

  return (
    <section ref={targetRef} className="group relative h-[90vh] w-[100vw] overflow-hidden bg-neutral-200">
      <div className="sticky top-0 flex h-screen items-center overflow-hidden">
        <motion.div style={{ x }} className="flex gap-4">
          {cards.map((card) => {
            return <Card card={card} key={card.id} />;
          })}
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Card = ({ card }) => {
  return (
    <div
      key={card.id}
      className="group relative h-[450px] w-[450px] overflow-hidden bg-neutral-200"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${card.url})`,
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
        }}
        className="absolute inset-0 z-0 transition-transform duration-300 group-hover:scale-110"
      ></div>
      <div className="absolute inset-0 z-10 grid place-content-center">
        <p className="bg-gradient-to-br from-white/20 to-white/0 p-8 text-6xl font-black uppercase text-white backdrop-blur-lg">
          {card.title}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;

const cards = [
  {
    url: "/imgs/abstract/1.jpg",
    title: "Title 1",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    url: "/imgs/abstract/2.jpg",
    title: "Title 2",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    url: "/imgs/abstract/3.jpg",
    title: "Title 3",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    url: "/imgs/abstract/4.jpg",
    title: "Title 4",
    id: 4,
  },
];
```

WIth this code, I'm getting like [this](https://www.loom.com/share/beeb572e122a4ea98782b86c5f75e522?sid=e7bc2382-2803-46d1-96d2-74e6c5646de9)

But I need to make it scroll to next slide with a single scroll smoothly (100vw). But now it's scrolling part by part only. Any help on this would be appreciated. You can also run the same code in your local with dependencies for clear view.